# What special characters does grep parse by default?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In a regular expression, which characters need escaping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20804/in-a-regular-expression-which-characters-need-escaping)

I know there is the `-E` flag which treats the "search term" as a regular expression. However, it seems that even without that, `grep` is treating some characters specially.

For example, if I run:

```
grep "$var" *
```

Then it lists every line of the file (I assume it's using `$` as the end-of-line regex). The period also seems to look for any character under certain circumstances.

So what are the special characters I need to be wary of when using `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

By default `grep` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE's).  Take a look at any resource on BRE's (e.g. `man grep` and `man regex`) to learn the syntax.  The `$` in `"$var"` is not being passed to `grep` at all because it is special to the shell.  If you have a shell variable named `var` its expansion is what `grep` actually sees.  If you don't, then `grep` just gets passed an empty string which matches everywhere.

EDIT: From the [POSIX specification for BRE's](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), the special characters are `*`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `[`, `\`

If you just want to match literal strings without having to worry about which characters have special meaning in BRE's, you should probably be using `fgrep` / `grep -F` instead (they are the same thing; both match fixed strings).