# How to grep through multiple files using lines from two input files as start and end of pattern?

Tags: grep, for

I would like to write a simple script that would use grep to search through a list of files. The current code looks something similar to this:

```
a= file1.txt 

b= file2.txt

for

do

grep '$a.*$b' /root/listoffiles/*php >> found.txt
```

done

`file1` and `file2` are both word lists. So this would search through the destination having multiple criteria. For example `$a` could be "hello" and `$b` "world" or the second line could be "red" and "tshirt". If it finds anything with two matching criteria then it would just save it into the file. The loop that I am using is not working and not efficient enough. I would like to get only the results for meeting criteria. Any suggestions?

Comment: is order important in matching? for ex: `world` should always be after `hello` or can it occur before also?

Comment: also, `hello` and `tshirt` (i.e word from file1 line1 and word from file2 line2) should also be matched? or is it only same line numbers from both files

Comment: file1 should be first then file2. My main problem is the loop itself because I have to read 2 files. for example I was able to create a loop with a single file where it greps through the list and trying to find matching words in the destination folder. Thanks

Comment: line 1 in file1 and line 1 in file2 should match.

Comment: ok, try this single command instead of script, `grep -f <(pr -mts'.*' file1.txt file2.txt) /root/listoffiles/*php >> found.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You would first have to [escape the special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20804) in those two files (if any) and then join them via e.g. `paste` to end up with a list of patterns that you would then use via `grep`'s `-f` ... and unless you have too many files you don't need a loop as `grep` accepts multiple arguments:

```
paste -d'.*' <(sed 's/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g' file1.txt) /dev/null \
<(sed 's/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g' file2.txt) | grep -f - /root/listoffiles/*php >> found.txt
```

Comment: hi, This seems to be a working solution, but. What if I got in file1 something like yellow-stone and 2.1.2. in file2. How can I ignore the special characters? So it would search yellow stone 2 1 2 in this order

Comment: @Stephen - I'm afraid you'll have to elaborate on that (and not only that because your post is already unclear - there are two interpretations of your question and, as a result, two different answers...) Anyway, my current solution will search for for a string matching `yellow-stone.*2\.1\.2` - I don't quite get what you mean by "_ignore special characters_" and "_search yellow stone 2 1 2 in this order_" (why spaces there ?) How do you define "special characters" and what do you mean by "ignoring them" ?

Comment: for example ignore the "-" and "." between the strings

Comment: @Stephen - let me put it this way: given two strings (from the same line in each of those two files) `yellow-stone` and `2.1.2` **what is the actual regex that those two strings are expected to produce** ?

Answer (score 0):

Build a pattern from the word lists. From `file1.txt` containing e.g. `one`, `un`, `eins` and `file2.txt` containing `two`, `deux`, `zwei`, you need to get the regular expression (in ERE syntax)

```
(one|un|eins).*(two|deux|zwei)
```

If the word lists don't contain any characters that are special in a regex then all you need to do is replace newlines by `|` (the “or” operator) except the final one.

```
words1=$(tr '\n' '|' <file1.txt); words1=${words1%\|}
words2=$(tr '\n' '|' <file2.txt); words2=${words2%\|}
grep -E "($words1).*($words2)"
```

If the word lists might contain special characters then you need to quote them.

```
words1=$(<file1.txt tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/[][\\().*?+|]/\\&/g'); words1=${words1%\|}
words2=$(<file2.txt tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/[][\\().*?+|]/\\&/g'); words2=${words2%\|}
grep -E "($words1).*($words2)"
```

Note that if you don't care about the order of the words and you can accept overlapping matches (e.g. accept `twone` as containing both `one` and `two`) then all you need is two grep invocations:

```
grep -f file1.txt | grep -f file2.txt
```